# GUI to oracle Change data capture

Tags: oracle, user-interface, cdc

I'm learning how to implement change data capture in oracle. However, not being a DB specialist but rather a DEV, i find the process tedious with respect to other things that i have to do. I end up doing it because my DBA/DEVOP don't want to take care of it.

Hence i was wondering if there is any tool that can help set oracle change data capture. In other words a simple graphical user interface that would write the all code for me. Creation of change table, PL/SQL Script and etc....

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

topic duplicated in: [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87015/graphical-user-interface-to-change-data-capture-on-oracle)
What problem are you trying to solve?
How (when) will the CDC data be consumed

Are you planning to use something akin to: [Oracle 11.1 CDC doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/cdc.htm#CHDGABFJ)

Be sure to heed: [Oracle 11.2 CDC Warning](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16579/cdc.htm)

"Oracle Change Data Capture will be de-supported in a future release of Oracle Database and will be replaced with Oracle GoldenGate. Therefore, Oracle strongly recommends that you use Oracle GoldenGate for new applications."

The company I work for, Attunity, has a pretty slick GUI CDC tool called "Replicate".
It can directly apply changes to a selected target DB, or store changes to be applies. 
Many sources (Oracle, SQLserver, DB2...) many targets (Oracle. SQLserver, Netezza, Vertica,...)
Define your source and target DB, Search/Select source table, and one click to go. 
Optional transformations such as: table and column names, drop and add columns, calculate values.

Regards,
Hein.

Comment: Well, my target is not a relation base database but a triple-store also an RDF database. I'm using Stardog.

Comment: I just need to set up my change table and etc... graphically instead of doing it manually

Comment: Yeah, Attunity Replicate is not going to interface with NoSQL style databases directly. It can give you a GUI method to get change-tables in some ODBC/SQL database, or even CSV file, for subsequent processing. That would appear to be too big (costly) a hammer for your needs.